# how get resultat mariadb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mariadb, mariasql

This is my code:

```
var Maria = require('mariasql');

c = new Maria({
host: '127.0.0.1',
      user : 'root',
             password : 'maria',
                        db : 'gim'
});
c.query('SELECT * FROM contact WHERE id = ? AND nom = ?', [4, 'dupont'], function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        function getResult() {
            return rows;
        }
    }
});

c.end();
//get overs file 
console.log(getResult());
```

I want resultant data but `getResult()` is not defined.

How can I get resultant with node.js?

Comment: Maybe:  `rows = c.query(...  return rows ...);` ??

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several errors on your code.

Most of them related to basic JS programming concepts. So I will suggest you to look for some JS courses or tutorials.

- When you define `getResult` function, you're doing it inside of a function's clousure. Which means that, this function will be only accessible inside that function.
- The function where you've declared that `getResult` function, is actually a **callback** which is a function that will get executed as soon as some operation completes, normally an I/O intensive operation. Like in your case reading records from the database.
- When the last statement gets reached and executed your query did not return, as of per node.js non-blocking I/O, the control of the program executes `c.query...` and this is where you provide that *callback* that we mentioned earlier, so it can continue the execution of the rest of statements, and when the `c.query...` returns with the records, execute the callback with them as result. But by then `console.log...` would have been executed.

I'm not sure if this is an understandable answer, in part because the concepts that I've tried to explain are really basic to the language that you're using, so one more time I would suggest to start by a tutorial/course. There are some good ones on [CodeSchool](http://www.codeschool.com) and so many other sites.